# How to ignore double slashes while making a search query in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

For example, in the elastic search document, the string is stored as \\(\\log_4(3x^2+11x)=1\\)
The search query what I want to make it work is (log_4(3x^2+11x)=1).

What is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pattern_replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) which can replace the `\\` with `empty string`, below is the working example.

**Index Settings with custom analyzer using pattern_replace char filter**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_char_filter"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "my_char_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "\\\\(.*?)",
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
{
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
    "text": "\\(\\log_4(3x^2+11x)=1\\)"
}
```

**Generated tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "(log_4(3x^2+11x)=1)",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 22,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```